# Spring Webflux - Is it possible to enable/implement reactive push (instead of pull) backpressure?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is it possible to add reactive *push* backpressure for a `Publisher`?

From what I've seen, this is [very doable as a `Subscriber`](https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-core):

> Backpressure is when a downstream can tell an upstream to send it fewer data in order to prevent it from being overwhelmed.

I want to do the opposite -- I want to slow down or even pause the upstream when a particular downstream cannot keep up.  I was wondering if there was a nice reactive way to do this, like implementing a custom [`OverflowStrategy`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create)?  The [existing strategies](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.html) don't seem to fit my scenario.

I can't drop messages or error out, and I can't use the buffer strategy because I'll eventually run out of memory.

I can think of a custom solution where the objects that I emit are pooled so that I can limit the amount of objects in memory and release them when they are consumed, but this isn't doesn't seem like a reactive solution.

Comment: Could elaborate a bit? Reactive streams is a dual push+pull model where the publisher can push data when available as long as the subscriber can consume it. This is the very concept of backpressure. If the publisher is cold then it is already behaving like that. The overflow strategies are only required for hot publishers.

Comment: Sure, I have a cold `Flux` sink that is publishing data exposed as a REST endpoint.  There are other clients that consume this endpoint and perform some processing.  Some clients cannot consume fast enough, and eventually cause my server to be out of memory, since the default overflow strategy is `BUFFER`.  I'd like to avoid mandating clients implement their own backpressure mechanism.  Do you think that's possible?